# viewport height (100vh) on mobile leads to unwanted scroll

Tags: css, angular, height, viewport

I'm developing a theme for mobile in Angular 10.

And I've used `vh` to set height of components.

My app is pretty much complex and I've set height in `vh` in 100s of places. Altering every height to `px's` or `%`  isn't possible for me.

I'm fully aware that this issue isn't new and there are many solutions available on different forums. But none worked for me.

I used following script.
But I got error `--vh` is undefined.

```
<script>
     window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      // We execute the same script as before
      let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    body {
      height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
    }
  </style>
```

Even if somehow I manage to make it work I got to alter it in many places which isn't possible for me.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things.

First the code to set the CSS variable --vh. It needs to be run on the initial and any subsequent load as well as on resize:

```js
function resize() {
  // We execute the same script as before
  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
window.addEventListener('load', resize);
```

```css
body {
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Second, altering the use of vh to --vh.

I guess you'll need to set up an edit macro, or just set up a find and replace and go to next by hand as you'll probably want to check you have the substitutions right.

e.g. for 80vh you'll want `calc(var(--vh) * 80);` Actually, I've done it on a project and it wasn't too bad, but I didn't have hundreds which you mention. Luckily vh is an unusual string so not too hard to find the next one.